# Machine Learning Algorithm for 'Performance Rating' to Employees

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, decision-trees, linear-regression, machine-learning-model

Which Machine Learning Algorithm should i use for Assigning 'Performance Rating' to each Employee based on his LeaveDaysCount and LeaveExtensionPeriod(If Extended).

Comment: I don't think you will need a ML algorithm for this. This could be achieved by using a score-based algorithm. There's nothing to learn for a ML algorithm.

Comment: Okay. is Elo Rating Algorithm sufficient for this problem